# "Try" and "Except" in my program (python)

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:  #code should only allow integers to be inputed
        try: 
            rolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls: "))
            break
        except:
            print("You did not enter a valid Integer")
```

output works for characters like "b" and "d"
but when I put a zero in, I still get the ZeroDivisionError

I want the code to only allow an integer.

later on in the code I tried this

```
if rolls <= 0:
    print("You must enter at least one roll")
    print()
```

but it doesnt stop the code from running and the error still pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no division in the posted code and it will *not* throw a ZeroDivisionError.

The exception is likely thrown when `xyz / rolls` is done *later* (*outside* that try/catch), when `rolls` evaluates to 0.

Fix the logic so as to not even allow such invalid division to occur! Maybe "0" means to exit the game? Or maybe "0" means that the user should be asked for another roll?

---

FWIW, here is modified code to read input that won't accept "0":

```
while True:  #code should only allow integers to be inputed
    try: 
        rolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls: "))
        if rolls > 0:
            break
    except:
        pass # don't do anything here, because we print below for
             # exceptions and when the if guarding the break failed.
    print("You must enter a valid roll (> 0)")
```

Comment: **edit: actually that didnt work, doing the if statement.

With the restart if I enter a 0, then later a 5 it'll run the program, but print the error afterwards.

Comment: @Moose You must guard the actual operation (`xyz / rolls`) that can cause the exception.

Comment: Explain it like I'm five =p
Im very new to programming. I guess what my understanding with the try and excepts were that as long as I had that last except, it would cover all errors.

Comment: @Moose You'll get better input if you show the code that uses `rolls` and describe how it is supposed to act when 0 is entered, and if it is even valid. In many simple programs, entering 0 might "end the game" or "exit the number entry stage".

Comment: Your most recent edit fixed the problem. Thank you very much. Thanks for explaining out the pass part as well.